# Returning the text of closest clicked element that has ad data attribute (Google Tag Manager)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors, attributes, google-tag-manager

I have a following code:

`<div class="sc-gPEVay JHVSz" data-locator="category" data-values="9AAF500002"><button class="sc-jWBwVP mdc-ripple-surface ebJHFF" data-locator="category-header" style="align-items: stretch; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); border-style: none; box-shadow: none; color: rgb(114, 114, 114); cursor: pointer; display: flex; font-style: inherit; font-variant: inherit; font-weight: inherit; font-stretch: inherit; font-size: 13px; line-height: inherit; font-family: inherit; margin: 0px; outline: none; padding: 0px; text-decoration: none; width: 100%;"><i aria-hidden="true" class="sc-brqgnP material-icons_mi_2breL5T5PilQnhNwuNJjVT material-icons_mi-arrow-drop-down_1Yg8_MNgX_6a8ed5ZighLw ygVYg" data-locator="category-expander" style="height: 24px; margin-right: 12px; transition: transform 175ms ease 0s; transform: rotate(-90deg);"></i><div class="sc-cMljjf bIKLMh" data-locator="category-label" style="font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; margin-top: 4px; min-height: 24px; text-align: left;"> My Text </div></button><div class="sc-jDwBTQ kFDQOY" data-locator="category-children" style="margin-left: 10px;"></div></div>`

What i want to achieve is to return the text "My Text" no matter where the click lands.

I tried:

```
function (){

var $clickElement = $({{Click Element}});

var $x = $clickElement.closest('i').find('div');

return $x.text();
```

PS. I cant/dont want to use the classes (they can change)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [attribute selector](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp).

```
var $clickElement = $({{Click Element}});
var clickedOnMyText = $clickElement.attr('data-locator') === 'category-label';
var $x;
if(clickedOnMyText) {
  $x = $clickElement;
} else {
  $x = $clickElement.find('[data-locator="category-label"]');
}
return $x.text();
```